# Remove shadow from mkannotationview image

Tags: ios, mkannotationview

When using a mkannotationview with a image containing a lot of transparency in it I get a dropshadow generated by ios around the image block.

Is there a way to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Just a guess: did you try setting the MKAnnotationView layer's shadowColor to UIColor clearColor? ie myAnnotationView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

Comment: Excellent idea, didn't work though :(

Comment: Did you find a answer for this eventually?